# How to write PM2 logs to sumologic?

Tags: node.js, pm2, sumologic

I'm developing a small NodeJS server that will run under PM2 management.
We use Sumologic as a centralized log solution in our production environment.

How do I send PM2 logs to Sumologic, preferably keeping "console.log" statements in my NodeJS code to keep local development simple?

Answer (score 3):

PM2 has a good log management system, where you can choose where to save logs [[Log Management Documentation]](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/log-management/?utm_source=pm2&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=rebranding)

Once that is done, you will now need to read the logs file and send its contents to SumoLogic for ingestion.

To handle sending logs to sumologic via javascript, you will want to use [sumo-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sumo-logger). Install this in you application.

Next, create a file mySumoLogger.js that reads the logs files, requires sumo-logger and uses it to send the data to sumologic at regular intervals.
You can also try out [pm2-logrotate](https://github.com/keymetrics/pm2-logrotate) to rotate your log files and coordinate it with the intervals at which the data is pushed to sumo.

Finally, you will need to run mySumoLogger.js in  parallel to you application(s). So your pm2 ecosystem.config.js will look something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    { ...your app1  },
    { ...your app2 },
    {
      name: 'sumologicLogger',
      script: 'node <path>/mySumoLogger.js',
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same use case to integrate PM2 to sumologic and tried to dig through the same link mentioned above. 
Seems like PM2 removed the integration module for Sumo Logic or probably to any other log management products. 
Instead, they are asking users to signup for enterprise edition.